# How to calculate number of full nodes on Bitcoin/Altcoin

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

What is the best way to calculate/estimate the total number of active miners/full nodes on Bitcoin/Altcoins?

Answer (score -1):

You can not calculate/estimate the total number of active miners. It is mainly because of the anonymity that the mining pools provide for the miners.

You can refer to the following link to know more about it.
[Check this out](https://www.edureka.co/community/7689/how-many-people-are-mining-bitcoins-all-over-the-world)

And similarly, you can not estimate the number of full nodes. There are few websites like
[this](https://bitnodes.earn.com/dashboard/?days=90) that show you the number of listening nodes. But there is no log of full nodes.